# How do I make my script either loop?

Tags: java

After "Please restart and try again" I'm trying to get the program to loop start to "Hello, what is your name?"

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Learning {

public static void main(String[] args) 

{
    System.out.println("Hello, What is your name?");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String yourName = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Is: " +yourName + " your name?");

    Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String isCorrect = scanner1.nextLine();

    if (isCorrect.equals("Yes"))
    {
        System.out.println("Thank you, Please proceed with the quiz!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Please restart and try again.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: `I'm trying to ...` Let's see it then. I don't see your attempt.

Comment: Have you read about [loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) yet?

Comment: I see no loop. Why you create no loop? How does loop not work if you do not create loop?

Comment: Sorry, i'll let you know I am completely and utterly new to Java and well out of my depth. After "please restart and try again" I would like the code to go back to "Hello, what is your name"

Comment: Add a loop and remove the `System.exit(0)` line... of course, you'll need to define some other way (inside the loop) to stop the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a while statement:

```
while(isCorrect.equals("noValue")&&(!isCorrect.equals("yes")||!isCorrect.equals("yes"))) {
```

So it continues until isCorrect dosn't equal "noValue" and it does equals "yes" or "Yes"
Here is the entire code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Learning {

public static void main(String[] args) {

String isCorrect = "noValue";
//If isCorrect equals noValue, keep going until it equals yes or Yes
while(isCorrect.equals("noValue")&&(!isCorrect.equals("yes")||!isCorrect.equals("Yes"))) {
    System.out.println("Hello, What is your name?");
    //You don't really need two scanners if they are both for the same thing
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String yourName = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Is: " +yourName + " your name?");

    isCorrect = scanner.nextLine();
    //include the if and else statements so the program knows what to say
    //and if it should repeat or not
    if(isCorrect.equals("yes")||isCorrect.equals("Yes")) {
        System.out.println("Thank you, please proceed with the quiz!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please try again");
        isCorrect = "noValue";
    }
}
//Continue with the quiz here!
}
}
```

I hope I helped!

Answer (score 1):

just use a do - while loop and remove System.exit(0);

```
do { 

    System.out.println("Hello, What is your name?");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String yourName = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Is: " +yourName + " your name?");

    Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String isCorrect = scanner1.nextLine();

    if (isCorrect.equals("Yes"))
    {
        System.out.println("Thank you, Please proceed with the quiz!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Please restart and try again.");
    }
} while (!isCorrect.equals("Yes"));
```